How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{100}}{1+x}dx$?
Q) How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{100}}{1+x}dx$$ ?
The only process which I know is by substituting $(1+x)$ as $u$ and then $dx$ becomes $du$.
Therefore,finally the integral will be
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(u-1)^{100}}{u}du$$
.
But this process is very very much lengthy and an impossible process.
This process works and seems to be good only for integrals like $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx$ when $n\leq 6$
Please help me out with this integral.

Hint: $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is a geometric series

Bigger and slightly better hint: long division. Try a small case and see if you can work out a pattern.

As suggested in the comments, since the interval of integration is between $0$ and $1$,
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-x)^n<\infty$$
and so, the integrand becomes
$$\frac{x^{100}}{1+x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nx^{100+n}.$$
Thus, the integral should now be easy to compute:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1\frac{x^{100}}{1+x}\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nx^{100+n}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_0^1x^{100+n}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{101+n}\overset{n+101\to n}{=}\sum_{n\geq 101}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\
&=\log 2\ -[(-1)^{101}\Phi(-1,1,101)+\log 2]\\
&=\Phi(-1,1,101)\approx 0.00497,
\end{aligned}$$
where
$$\Phi(z,s,a)\equiv\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^k}{(a+k)^s}$$
is the Lerch Transcendent.

We have for $J$ the integral to be computed:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &:= 
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{100}}{x+1}\;dx
=
\int_{0}^{1}\underbrace{\frac{x^{100}+x}{x+1}}
_{=x^{99}-x^{98}\pm\dots - x^4 + x^3 - x^2 + x}\;dx
-
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x+1}}_{=1-\log 2}\;dx
\\
&=
\frac 1{100}-\frac 1{99} +
\frac 1{98}-\frac 1{97} \pm \dots
-\frac 15 +\frac 14 -\frac 13 +\frac 12 -1 +\log 2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

You could apply the binomial theorem from where you are:
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k a^k b^{n-k}
$$
Then (as you forgot to change the bounds) you should have
$$\begin{align*}
\int_1^2 \frac{(u-1)^{100}}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u
&= \int_1^2 \frac 1 u \sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k} u^k (-1)^{100-k} \, \mathrm{d}u\\
&= \int_1^2  \sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k} u^{k-1} (-1)^{100-k} \, \mathrm{d}u\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{100} (-1)^{100-k} \binom{100}{k} \int_1^2  u^{k-1} \, \mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}$$
From here, just bear in mind that the $k=0$ integral will be of $\frac 1 u$, but otherwise the power rule applies.
It's still an unpleasant integral in this form somewhat, but using summation notation compactifies it.

Likewise, as brought up in the comments, the original integral in $x$ is one to whom the geometric series applies:
$$
\frac{1}{1-r} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k \text{ provided } |r|<1
$$
Then you can try this for a ratio of $r=-x$. The uniform convergence of the geometric series will allow you to interchange summation and integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{100}}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_0^1 x^{100} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k \, \mathrm{d}x
=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^1 x^{100+k} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

A third way would be to use a process akin to what I might use in the $n=1$ case.
Let
$$
I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Observe that
$$
I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n + x^{n-1} - x^{n-1}}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d} x - I_{n-1}
$$
You can evaluate the new integral and hence arrive at the recurrence relation
$$
I_n = \frac 1 n - I_{n-1}
$$
Clearly,
$$
I_0 = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \ln|1+x| \bigg|_0^1 = \ln 2
$$
You can use this information to iterate backwards or forwards to $I_{100}$ as you please.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{100} \over 1 + x}\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{100} - x^{101}\over 1 - x^{2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] & \sr{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{99/2} - x^{50}\over 1 - x}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 2}\bracks{\Psi\pars{51} - \Psi\pars{101 \over 2}}}}
\approx 0.004975 \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\Psi}$ is the $\ds{\it Digamma\ Function}$. Indeed, there's a closed expression beyond the above one -via $\ds{\it Gauss's\ Digamma\ Theorem}$- but it's somehow cumbersome. Namely,

